# How to crawl entire wikimapia?

Tags: string-formatting, nsdatecomponents, sdf

i need a sitemap which can help to people and google to know pages as well.
I've tried WebSphinx application.

I realize if I put wikipedia.org as the starting URL, it will not crawl further.

Hence, how to actually crawl the entire Wikipedia? Can anyone gimme some guidelines? Do I need to specifically go and find those URLs and put multiple starting URLs?

Anyone has suggestions of good website with the tutorial on usng WebSphinx's API?

Comment: A sitemap is a map of your own site

Answer (score 0):

Crawling wikipedia is a bad idea. It is hundreds of TBs of data uncompressed. I would suggest offline crawling by using various dumps provided by wikipedia. Find them here https://dumps.wikimedia.org/

You can create a sitemap for wikipedia using page meta information, external links, interwikilinks and redirects databases to name a few.

Comment: wikimapia not wikipedia